# Dynamically add styles to styled-jsx in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, next.js

Please see the code. I want to add some extra style for the about link conditionally, so I am adding it inside ${} of the template string for the  tag. This doesn't apply the new styles.

I have tried by concatenating the template strings. That didn't work either.

I cannot set style={style} in the  tag because then I won't be able to use the :hover style.

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import { withRouter } from 'next/router'

const Header = ({ children, router, href }) => {
  const isIndex = router.pathname === "/";
  const isAbout = router.pathname === "/about";
  return (
    <div>
        <Link href="/">
          <a id="home">Timers</a>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/about">
          <a id="about">About</a>
        </Link>
        <style jsx>{
          `
            a {
              font-family: 'Montserrat Subrayada', sans-serif;
              color: #ffffff;
              text-decoration: none;
              font-size: 24px;
              padding: 2px;
              margin-right: 30px;
            }
            a:hover {
              color: #000000;
              background-color: #ffffff;
              border-radius: 2px;
            }
            ${isAbout ? `
            #about {
              background-color: red;
              color: #000000;
            }
            #about:hover {
              background-color: blue;
              color: #ffffff;
            }
            ` : ``}

          `
        }</style>
    </div>
)}

export default withRouter(Header)
```

How can I apply conditional styles?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to only change the property values dynamically, rather than add entire new selectors in a single conditional you must do it for each property, like this:

```
<style jsx>{
  `
    a {
      font-family: 'Montserrat Subrayada', sans-serif;
      color: #ffffff;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 24px;
      padding: 2px;
      margin-right: 30px;
      border-radius: 2px;
    }
    a:hover {
      color: #000000;
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    #home {
      background-color: ${isHome ? "#ffffff" : ""};
      color: ${isHome ? "#000000" : ""};
    }
    #about {
      background-color: ${isAbout ? "#ffffff" : ""};
      color: ${isAbout ? "#000000" : ""};
    }
  `
}</style>
```

(I figured out the answer to my question while I was asking it, so I thought i'd just post it with my answer anyway in case someone else needs it)

Comment: Use styled-components instead, it is more flexible and allows you to write styles as in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since styled-jsx compiles styles at build time, it cannot preprocess dynamic styles, this is a limitation that is mentioned in the docs[here](https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx#css-preprocessing-via-plugins)

> Plugins make it possible to use popular preprocessors like SASS, Less, Stylus, PostCSS or apply custom transformations to the styles at compile time.